# Calculated SubTotal By Year, measure not updating with Slicer in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, report, dax, dashboard

i have the below matrix where Market Company Name is in Matrix Rows as well as a Slicer.
i need to calculate the total per year irrespective market company name in order to calculate "% Distribution" which is equal to Premium per year per Market Company Name divide by Total Premium by Year.
[image]

i tried to create the below test measure:

```
test Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Production Reinsurer'[Gross Written Premium]),
                    ALLEXCEPT('Production Reinsurer','Production Reinsurer'[Year], 
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Entity Name],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Status],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Cover Type],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[LOB]))
```

it worked perfectly except if i select a market company name from the slicer, all figures will be wrong.

And if i add Market Company Name to the formula it will calculate the Sub total per year per company which is wrong:

```
test Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Production Reinsurer'[Gross Written Premium]),
                    ALLEXCEPT('Production Reinsurer','Production Reinsurer'[Year], 
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Entity Name],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Status],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Cover Type],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[LOB],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Market Company Name]))
```

[image]

appreciate your assistance

Georges

Comment: I figure your test Measure is a created column? I had a similar issue where a calculated column would not show up correctly for my slicer selection. I fixed this by first calculating specific measures before creating a custom column. This might help you to

Comment: No, it is a measure not a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using the below measure:

```
test Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Production Reinsurer'[Gross Written Premium]),
                    ALLEXCEPT('Production Reinsurer','Production Reinsurer'[Year], 
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Entity Name],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Status],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Cover Type],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[LOB],
                                'Production Reinsurer'[Market Company Name]),
                                ALLSELECTED('Production Reinsurer'[Market Company Name]))
```

regards,
Georges